# iOS Safari NodeIterator nextNode returns null

Tags: javascript, ios, dom, safari

Safari on iPhone 6 with iOS 9 returns in this example `null`:

HTML:

```
<template id="example">
  <p>Hello world!</p>
  <p>Hello world!</p>
  <p>Hello world!</p>
</template>
```

Javascript:

```
var SourceNode = document.getElementById("example");
var TemplateNode = document.importNode(SourceNode.content, true);
var Nodes = document.createNodeIterator(TemplateNode);

console.log(Nodes.nextNode());

var Node;
while(Node = Nodes.nextNode())
{
  console.log("foo");
}
```

`foo` in the while loop get's never outputed.

`console.log(Nodes.nextNode());` outputs `null`.

It works in current Chrome, Firefox and Edge.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LdtxLuvh/1/

Anything wrong with my code or a bug?

Comment: Have you checked if that JS feature is available on iOS 9?

Comment: `createNodeIterator` is working, `Nodes` is not null. MDN says it's supported since 3.0.

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/NodeIterator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating to iOS 10 anything works, so I think it's an iOS 9 related bug.